# Semantic vs. Functional Interpretation of has_many/belongs_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I'm a Rails beginner and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I should design my database schema.  Here's a quick breakdown of some of my models:

- `Submission`: Contains multiple `Guesses`.
- `Guess`: Contains one `Song`.
- `Song`: Contains song-related info, has a many-to-many relationship with `Shows`.
- `Show`: Contains show-related info, including `Songs` that were played.

The relationship between the last two models are managed through the `Song_Show` relationship model.  Things get a little trickier when I try and relate the `Guess` model to the `Song` model.  Semantically, I think of it like each `Guess` `has_one` `Song` and each `Song` `belongs_to` many `Guesses`; however, there is no `belongs_to_many` relation.

In the classic example that uses the `Customer` and `Order` models, the semantic relationship matches the Rails relationship - each `Order` `belongs_to` a `Customer` and a `Customer` `has_many` `Orders`; however, trying to apply that logic to my example doesn't quite work if the proper way to do things is a `Song` `has_many` `Guesses` and each `Guess` `belongs_to` a `Song`.  Is the way I'm thinking about these relationships semantically getting in my way of understanding Rails associations?

On a related topic, creating all of these relationships seems to be a hassle, at least for the initial version of this application where both the `Guess` and `Song` models seem rather useless, as they each essentially store a single `song_name` property.  One of the critical features of the application is to compare a `Submission` to a `Song` and see if any of the `song_names` from the `Submission` match those in the `Show`.  Is it a bad idea to simply serialize a list of `song_names` in both the `Submission` and `Show` instances and compare those directly, rather than complicating things with the `Song` and `Guess` models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get too bogged down by the meaning of `has_many` and `belongs_to`. At some point in your Rails career, you'll start to see them for what they really mean: which model keeps track of the relationship.

In a `has_many` relationship, it's the other model that keeps track of the relationship. If a Song has_many Guesses, then the Guess would have the song_id.

In a `belongs_to` relationship, the class that you're in is the thing that keeps the id. If a Guess `belongs_to` a Song, then the Guess has the song_id.

In a `has_many...through` model, it's the joining class that keeps track of everything.

As for your last question, I think you have to figure out how you're going to compare Guesses to Songs. Seems like a Guess might not merit it's own class—could be serialized—but a Song could probably merit its own class. Doing it like this might make it easier to search too:

```
Song.where(song_name: @submission.guesses) # where guesses is an array.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly helpful.  One follow-up question that comes to mind is how do I manage the `Song` model across multiple use cases?  A `Song` will have a many-to-many relationship with the `Show` model, but does it makes sense to also have it have a many-to-many relationship with the `Submission` model as well (assuming no `Guess` model)?  In other words, would it make sense to have `@submission.guesses` tie to the `Song` model (likely using a `has_many...through`) or should it just be an array of `song_names` derived from the user input?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it makes a lot of sense to have a Guess just be a join table from Submission to Song. Or, similar but lighter weight, a guess could just be an array of song_ids, and you could write your own method to access songs from Submission. That would be, in fact, a `belongs_to` many, which is not an actual association because it's klunky to search the database for arrays.

Comment: Thanks again - I like the former idea, where I still keep the `Guess` model, but it serves as the joiner for `Submission` and `Song`.  I'll start there and see how it goes!